# Angular2 - Where can be endpoints configured using InMemoryWebApiModule?

Tags: angular, http, local-storage, angular2-services, endpoint

I am following [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) (oficial Angular2 "Quick Start" tutorial)

At the end of it, there are couple of http requests (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE...), which, instead of calling a real server, are simulated using this lines in the `app.module.ts`:

```
// The HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule module intercepts HTTP requests
// and returns simulated server responses.
// Remove it when a real server is ready to receive requests.
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
  InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
)
```

Here is an example of a HTTP Request made by the application:

```
  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

  /** GET heroes from the server */
  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
      );
  }
```

The question: is there any way to configure the endpoints expected by this InMemoryDataService? So, for instance, I could change the Url to `api/heroes/getAll`.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Szarik recommendations, I follow [this link](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api), which has the answer. Actually, it's the official specification of the Library I am using: in-memory-web-api

Diving a little in the README.md, we reach this:

> You can override the default parser by implementing a parseRequestUrl method in your InMemoryDbService.
>
> The service calls your method with two arguments.
>
> 1. url - the request URL string
> 2. requestInfoUtils - utility methods in a RequestInfoUtilities object, including the default parser. Note that some values have not yet been set as they depend on the outcome of parsing.
>
> Your method must either return a ParsedRequestUrl object or null|undefined, in which case the service uses the default parser. In this way you can intercept and parse some URLs and leave the others to the default parser.

So that was it!

Answer (score 0):

To examplify the answer above: 
The 'forRoot' takes optional settings, and among these an 'apiBase'. To match an endpoint of

`private url = '/some/endpoint/responseExample';`

set the corresponding 'apiBase' without prefix and suffix slashes:

```
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDbItemService, { apiBase: 'some/endpoint'})
```

The 'responseExample' is the actual data.

```
   createDb() {
    const responseExample = {[some:'structure']}

    return { responseExample };
  }
```